# How can commit data update in Microsoft SQL sever?

Tags: c#, sql-server

In a web app, I am using SQL server. However, when I try to store some bulk amount of data, it misses some of the records and does not insert them into the database. I want to know whether there is any commit statement or synchronization for the database? Data is being sent object by object using an ajax call.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    int surah = Convert.ToInt32(Request["surah"]);
    string verse = Request["data"];
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\PEACE_QURAN.MDF;Integrated Security=True";
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    string query = "insert into Ayyat_Translation_Language_old_20131209 values(null,null,"+surah+",'"+verse+"')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\Office_Work\Peace_Quran\Peace_Quran\Files\ExceptionFile.txt", true);
    file.WriteLine("exception details : "+e.ToString());
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: The code could use some refactoring, but it appears that it should work. Are you getting an error? If not, please qualify why you don't believe it's working more clearly.

Comment: NO Error or no exception is generated. but when i refresh my database, it shows 5 to 10 less entries than i entered. is that due to ajax call ?

Comment: Your code shows a single row insert (no loop). Are you using the same code 10 times? Also, your exception code should show the message (e.message) and throw an exception, otherwise it could go undetected.

Answer (score 0):

As you understand, the records cannot get lost in the way. Either the INSERT statement would execute, or you would get an exception. Since neither is happening, I believe that you loose something in the request generating mechanism.

I would strongly suggest to put some **logging** message on each request. You will probably find out that your requests are less than you thought. This could be for a number of reasons, but since I don't know the exact mechanism calling the server side code, I cannot have an opinion.

Hope I helped!